# How to make non-static gameobjects brighter?

Tags: unity, lighting, lightmap

I placed non-static gameobject in the scene. Look at this picture:

[image]

[image]

You can see the lighter, but it's too dark, way darker than others. The only difference between the lighter and the  other objects are the fact that other objects are static objects.

How do I make this object brighter in this case? Why do non-static objecs have different light results?

Comment: Static objects use a baked lightmap to account for all the bounced indirect lighting in the scene. For dynamic objects, you need cheaper approximations like skybox lighting or light probes. Show us more of how you've configured the renderer on this object, lights shining on it, and the lighting settings for the scene, and we can help identify what settings to change.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you for detailed answer. I just increased reflection probe's intensity now it's way much better. Thanks!

Comment: If that solved your problem, please consider writing up your steps as an answer post, so other developers can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DMGregory said, I solved this issue to placing reflection probes in there and increase the intensity, is now non-static objects are brighter enough.